# Use two Threading.Timers simultaneous

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm using a `Threading.Timer` like this in my application (running on `WM 6.5`):

```
Using New Threading.Timer(AddressOf CallSync, Nothing, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20))
    While True
    End While
End Using
```

Now I need another timer like the above one, complete independent and with its own timespan.
What woulb be the best way to accomplish this?
Do I need a second, seperate `thread` for this?

Comment: Sure, a second timer for another task would be a consistent desision.

Comment: @Egor4eg Where would I implement the second `Using-part`/`Timer`-statement?

Comment: It depends on the purpose of that timer and the architecture of the app. It's not possible to help you based on the provided info.

Comment: @Egor4eg Simple said, one task is doing `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s on a table (executing `CallSync` once every 20 minutes), while the new, second task should check if the database connection is alright (once every 60 minutes for i.e.)

Comment: You can try to start the timers in course: the first timer (as in your example) and then the second one.